# Spark cluster - Workers and Executors repeated twice

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, installation

I had a spark cluster with 1 worker and 2 executors. I wanted to update spark, so I deleted all the corresponding installation files in worker and executor nodes and did a fresh installation of the new version of spark. Now after restarting my workers and executors with the new installation of spark, I see that the available number of instances have been double (6 instead of 3) in the spark master default web UI on port 8080.

I stopped the cluster and the web UI shows 3 previous instance. So I doubt that my previous installation os spark has something to do with it. How can I check it and ensure only new installation is valid.

And moreover, in the web UI on 8080, the version of spark displayed is 3.4.1.

PS. I use CentOS 8 on all the machines, Java SDK 17, Spark 3.5 (newly installed) and Spark 3.4.1 was previously installed.

Comment: Did you stop the previous master/workers? Also, what is your deployment type: Standalone/YARN etc?

Comment: Its a standalone installation. No I might have not stopped the previous installation. But I dont have the stop-all.sh of the previous installation anymore.

Comment: Can you try killing the earlier processes?

Comment: Tried killing the earlier processes. But it did not work.

Comment: What exactly did not work? Killing the processes or even after killing the spark UI lists 3.4.1?